# PHPExcel Class 'PHPExcel_Worksheet' not found

Tags: php, phpexcel, fatal-error, autoloader

I got the following error when importing PHPExcel into my framework:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_Worksheet' not found in /var/www/library/phpexcel.class.php on line 109
```

I am autoloading my classes including PHPExcel but it looks like PHPExcel uses `spl_autoload_register` to register any existing autoloader functions with SPL. I also tried echoing the files as they were being loaded and got

```
/var/www/library/PHPExcel/Shared/ZipStreamWrapper.php
/var/www/library/PHPExcel/Shared/String.php
Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_Worksheet' not found in /var/www/library/phpexcel.class.php on line 109
```

So it seems `Autoloader.php` isn't the issue since `ZipStreamWrapper.php` and `String.php` are being loaded.  Any suggestions at all would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Assuming you are using your own autoloader for other elements of your site, have you followed the instructions in section 3.2 of the developer documentation?

Comment: Ha, I feel like an idiot.  I was under the impression PHPExcel handled this.  I just re-defined my existing autoload function with spl_autoload_register and it worked.  Thanks

Comment: PHPExcel ___tries___ to handle it, with varying degrees of success given the variety of ways in which autoloaders can be defined... which is why we recommend redefining existing autoloaders to use spl_autoload_register()