# Class 'PHPExcel_Worksheet' not found

Tags: php, phpexcel

This is my first time using PHPexcel and I'm having a bit of trouble in compiling my code its giving me an error: 
**Class 'PHPExcel_Worksheet' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\sampleexcel\Classes\PHPExcel.php on line 371**

I've looked up online and saw that there's a problem with the autoloader?

What I want to do is to get data from my database and export it as an excel file with multiple sheets.

Can you help me in debugging this code or giving me hints on how to fix the autoloader?

Here's my **index php code:**

```
   if (function_exists('__autoload')) {
    //    Register any existing autoloader function with SPL, so we don't 
  get any clashes
    spl_autoload_register('__autoload');
}
//    Register ourselves with SPL
return spl_autoload_register(array('PHPExcel_Autoloader', 'Load'));

  include 'config.php'; 
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Create a first sheet, representing sales data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Something');

// Rename sheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Name of Sheet 1');

// Create a new worksheet, after the default sheet
$objPHPExcel->createSheet();

// Add some data to the second sheet, resembling some different data types
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'More data');

// Rename 2nd sheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Second sheet');

// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="sample.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Here's my code for config.php:

```
<?php


    $server = "localhost";
    $db_uname = "root";
    $db_passwd = "";
    $db = "svr";

    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "svr") or  die("Could not connect: " .mysqli_error($connect));

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried redefining your existing autoload function with spl_autoload_register? As mentioned in the comments of this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646938/phpexcel-class-phpexcel-worksheet-not-found)

Comment: Haven't done that yet.... let me try to edit my code

Comment: UPDATE: I still have no luck in doing this... I added      if (function_exists('__autoload')) {
        //    Register any existing autoloader function with SPL, so we don't get any clashes
        spl_autoload_register('__autoload');
    }
    //    Register ourselves with SPL
    return spl_autoload_register(array('PHPExcel_Autoloader', 'Load'));

and its giving me this error Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Passed array does not specify an existing static method

Comment: You should not need to do the autoloading for PHPExcel at all.... PHPExcel should handle this when you include `Classes/PHPExcel.php`, and doing it yourself manually will adversely affect PHPExcel's own inclusion of the autoloader

Comment: But your call to `spl_autoload_register('__autoload');` will potentially interfere with PHPExcel's autoloader..... see [the docs here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/02-Architecture.md#lazy-loader)